# can't read .wav in scipy: Unexpected end of file

Tags: python, scipy, wav

If I use the following code in Python:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
fs,data=wavfile.read('synth/perc0.wav')
```

on a percussive sound I have created on Python and saved on my computer as "perc0.wav", "data" gives me a list of floats that form the sound. If I play the array I hear the same sound I previously made, again.

However, if I use it on a song that I converted to a .wav-file using "Ontiva" (that I am able to play just fine using "Groove Music" or "Windows Media Player"), I get the error: "Unexpected end of file.", even when I use a very short song like My Bloody Valentine's "Touched".

What am I doing wrong? Please don't call this a duplicate as I'm sure someone will eagerly do, because I have scoured the internet for anyone having the same issue as me, but all I found is the above code.

Comment: "Please don't call this a duplicate...I have scoured the internet" This doesn't mean you didn't miss something. If there is already a duplicate question that helps answer yours, then you should be happy to have your question marked as a duplicate because you will get your answer quicker than if someone has to type the same answer again.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with Ontiva. Have you tried other converters?

Comment: `wav` may have different compressions - maybe `scipy` works only with some type of compressions or with uncompressed `wav`. You should check in documentation.

Comment: in doc [scipy.io.wavfile.read](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) you can see: `This function cannot read wav files with 24-bit data.`

Comment: It was an issue with Ontiva. Thanks everyone for the contributions! Don't know what the issue is with Ontiva still. The file that worked has the same bit rate as the Ontiva file, so I don't know what's going on. But I'm happy I found a method that works now. For any future readers, I have used Freemake Video Downloader to download the video as mp3, and then Freemake Audio Converter to convert it to .wav. So that's one method that works.